# How sum of specific attribute value in xml?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML document and i want do the sum of Minutes in Forground and Minutes Open for each Computername

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <row>
    <Computername>A00123</Computername>
    <Full Name>Bob Robert</Full Name>
    <Username>brobert</Username>
    <Model>toto 1 (Late 2017)</Model>
    <Serial Number>C02EX1</Serial Number>
    <App Name>test 3.app</App Name>
    <Version Number>24.0.0 v1 FRA (3008)</Version Number>
    <Minutes in Forground>4</Minutes in Forground>
    <Minutes Open>4</Minutes Open>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Computername>B00265</Computername>
    <Full Name>Lise Mona</Full Name>
    <Username>lmona</Username>
    <Model>titi 2 (Early 2018)</Model>
    <Serial Number>C02HX2</Serial Number>
    <App Name>test 3.app</App Name>
    <Version Number>24.0.0 v1 FRA (3008)</Version Number>
    <Minutes in Forground>5</Minutes in Forground>
    <Minutes Open>1359</Minutes Open>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Computername>B00265</Computername>
    <Full Name>Lise Mona</Full Name>
    <Username>lmona</Username>
    <Model>titi 2 (Early 2018)</Model>
    <Serial Number>C02HX2</Serial Number>
    <App Name>test 3.app</App Name>
    <Version Number>24.0.0 v1 FRA (3008)</Version Number>
    <Minutes in Forground>1</Minutes in Forground>
    <Minutes Open>1479</Minutes Open>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Computername>B00265</Computername>
    <Full Name>Lise Mona</Full Name>
    <Username>lmona</Username>
    <Model>titi 2 (Early 2018)</Model>
    <Serial Number>C02HX2</Serial Number>
    <App Name>test 3.app</App Name>
    <Version Number>24.0.0 v1 FRA (3008)</Version Number>
    <Minutes in Forground>99</Minutes in Forground>
    <Minutes Open>390</Minutes Open>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Computername>C00854</Computername>
    <Full Name>Sheila Smith</Full Name>
    <Username>ssmith</Username>
    <Model>tata 1 (Middle 2019)</Model>
    <Serial Number>C02ZX3</Serial Number>
    <App Name>test 3.app</App Name>
    <Version Number>24.0.0 v1 FRA (3008)</Version Number>
    <Minutes in Forground>12</Minutes in Forground>
    <Minutes Open>1331</Minutes Open>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Computername>C00854</Computername>
    <Full Name>Sheila Smith</Full Name>
    <Username>ssmith</Username>
    <Model>tata 1 (Middle 2019)</Model>
    <Serial Number>C02ZX3</Serial Number>
    <App Name>test 3.app</App Name>
    <Version Number>24.0.0 v1 FRA (3008)</Version Number>
    <Minutes in Forground>2</Minutes in Forground>
    <Minutes Open>13</Minutes Open>
  </row>
</root>
```

I would like to write an XSLT document that would transform the original document XML to have as an exit, for each computer keep, Computername,Full Name, Username, Model, Serial Number, App Name, Version Number and sum all Minutes in forground and Minutes Open like the following Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <row>
    <Computername>A00123</Computername>
    <Full Name>Bob Robert</Full Name>
    <Username>brobert</Username>
    <Model>toto 1 (Late 2017)</Model>
    <Serial Number>C02EX1</Serial Number>
    <App Name>test 3.app</App Name>
    <Version Number>24.0.0 v1 FRA (3008)</Version Number>
    <Minutes in Forground>4</Minutes in Forground>
    <Minutes Open>4</Minutes Open>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Computername>B00265</Computername>
    <Full Name>Lise Mona</Full Name>
    <Username>lmona</Username>
    <Model>titi 2 (Early 2018)</Model>
    <Serial Number>C02HX2</Serial Number>
    <App Name>test 3.app</App Name>
    <Version Number>24.0.0 v1 FRA (3008)</Version Number>
    <Minutes in Forground>105</Minutes in Forground>
    <Minutes Open>3228</Minutes Open>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Computername>C00854</Computername>
    <Full Name>Sheila Smith</Full Name>
    <Username>ssmith</Username>
    <Model>tata 1 (Middle 2019)</Model>
    <Serial Number>C02ZX3</Serial Number>
    <App Name>test 3.app</App Name>
    <Version Number>24.0.0 v1 FRA (3008)</Version Number>
    <Minutes in Forground>14</Minutes in Forground>
    <Minutes Open>1344</Minutes Open>
  </row>
</root>
```

How can I do? xslt? xsltproc?
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: This is a [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info) question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for your answers michael.hor257k! I tried to look with the xslt grouping but I admit that this language is a little too complicated for me ....